# Audio doesn't stops even after closing the Video

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio

I was seeing youtube video on my laptop. Then suddenly audio started repeating itself again and again in unusual way 
and then I closed the youtube tab still I can hear the audio.

But Once I restart Laptop the problem disappears.

But again after sometime of watching video, This problem happens again.

Can someone help me out to overcome this problem?
I am using Windows 10

Comment: Guys if you didn't understand the question, just mention the part that has problem in the question.....

Comment: rather than only just disliking it

Comment: It's a very basic issue and you have done an awkward job of describing the problem. Looking at the reason for the Close Votes will give you a clue as to what about it needs to be fixed. That said, I'm pretty certain I know what your problem is and what you need to do to resolve it.

Comment: A few tips: Your use of Bold serves no purpose except to make the question difficult to read. Using ellipses (...) is just a sign that you aren't confident in your sentence structure and communication in general. More information about your laptop's hardware can also be helpful.

Comment: Okay next time I will take care of what you mentioned while forming questions

Comment: Not next time. Use the Edit button above to improve this question and it'll go a long way towards stopping the downvote and close-vote parade.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, when closing an application, the program continues running in the background.

That is what is happening here.

Rather than restarting your computer, simply open the Task Manager, find the Chrome executables still running, and end them

To hopefully prevent the problem from occurring again, try using a different web browser, and update your computer and all software and drivers to the latest current versions.